# Can't make all elements of a class appear after delays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make all the elements of a certain class show, but each after a delay.

This code shows all the elements instantly, but I want to wait 1 second between each.

```
$('.notify').each(function(index) {
    $(this).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

I've tried using setTimeout but it 'loses' the element variable (the one called 'this'). I've also tried using .delay() but that just makes all the elements show together after 1 second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$('.notify').each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay(i * 1000).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

This would fade in the first instantly, the second after a 1000ms, etc...just tweak the delay if needed, add some number of ms to create a delay before the first if you want.

Note: this delay is between the *start* of each [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/), if you want to wait a full second after if *finishes* fading in, add the duration to that 1000 (default duration is 400ms).